# How to install Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am following a guide that says I have to install "Eclipse"

I'm been stuck in the beginning for 48 hours, because I can't figure out the task: "target SDK and compile with SDK 20."

But maybe it's because I'm missing this Eclipse-thing.

Do you know if this is this the eclipse that can help building an Android app?: https://www.eclipse.org/

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just download android studio?

Comment: your guide is outdated.

Comment: eclipse is just a zip file extract it and you are done @jonas

Comment: I already downloaded and installed Android Studio.

Comment: Why do you all give me thumbs down on this? I spend many research hours on how to "target SDK and compile with SDK 20."

And still haven't found the correct answer.

Its not because I'm lazy, rather because I can't find a guide.

Answer (score 2):

here's a few steps you can follow. First download eclipse from either one of these links

1. [Windows x86_64](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip)
2. [Windows x86](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip)
3. [Mac x86_64](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip)
4. [Linux x86](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip)
5. [Linux x86_64](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip)

Or you can download eclipse from [here](http://eclipse.org) and add the Android plugin following these steps

- Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
- Click Add, at the top-right corner & in the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name & URL for the Location: `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
- Click OK. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
  In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
- Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish. If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK
- When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

That should be easy enough to get you started. the [archives](https://web.archive.org/web/20141113024741/http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) can be of great help but please note Google stopped supporting eclipse. Time to graduate to [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Comment: Thanks sir, I am downloading it now.